# JWT 401: Unauthorized in Slim 3 framework

Tags: php, json, authentication, jwt, slim

It's my first using slim 3 framework skeleton project, they say

> *There is also a skeleton project which will give you a quick-start for a sample application, so use that if you’d rather just have
>   something working rather than exploring how all the moving parts
>   work.*

In real life it so hard to integrate [JSON Web Token Authentication Middleware](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/slim-jwt-auth)

I try to following step by step in tutorial but still not working.
Please help me ?

this is my code

> middleware.php

```
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
  "path" => "/",
  "passthrough" => "/test",
  "secret" => "thisissecret"
]));
```

and my / route

> routes.php

```
$app->get('/',App\MemberController::class);
```

but the result is like this image below, 401: Unauthorized

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the parameter `secret`. It is **not** the the token. It is the **secret key** you use to sign the token.

It is up to you how you generate the token. There is for example an [online tool](https://jwt.io/). You can also generate token with PHP.

```
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$payload = [
    "sub" => "user@example.com"
];
$token = JWT::encode($payload, "thisissecret", "HS256");
```

Before using JWT is is good idea to read this [introduction](https://jwt.io/introduction/).

Answer (score 2):

## 1. Generate Token

Using [firebase/php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt)

```
$payload = [
    "sub" => "user@example.com"
];
    $token = JWT::encode($payload,'JWT-secret-key');
```

## 2. .htaccess Changes

If using Apache add the following to the .htaccess file. Otherwise PHP wont have access to Authorization: Bearer header

```
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

## 3. Middleware

```
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "path" => "/api",
    "passthrough" => ["/test"],
    "secret" => "JWT-secret-key",
    "secure" => false,
    "callback" => function ($request, $response, $arguments) use ($container) {
        $container["jwt"] = $arguments["decoded"];
    },
    "error" => function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
        $data["status"] = "0";
        $data["message"] = $arguments["message"];
        $data["data"] = "";
        return $response
        ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        ->write(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }
]));
```

## 4. Correct Request

[image]

## 5. Wrong Token Request

[image]

[Reference Link](https://appelsiini.net/projects/slim-jwt-auth/)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using apache server and serve over https protocol then your .htaccess file looks like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]

# Set the headers for the restful api
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH"
```